# Mails are not being sent using smtp client and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I have been going through some posts on Stack Overflow that look similar to mine and I have tweaked my code but it is still not working. My code is pated for your perusal below:

```
Dim ss As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    'Dim ss As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",465 )
    'Dim ss As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25)
    ss.Timeout = 10000
    ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    ss.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    ss.EnableSsl = True
    ss.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    ss.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("name@gmail.com", "name@123")


    Dim subject As String = "Approval request for Quotation with Order Number: " + Me.OrderNo

    Dim body As String = "Dear Sir/Madam," + vbCrLf + " This is to bring to your notice the quotation for the Client " + Me.cmbCustomer.SelectedItem.Text + " and Order Number " + Me.OrderNo & _
        " which is awaiting your approval." + vbCrLf + "Click here to view and approve the Quotation: http:192.168.20.7/appname/Sales/ManageInvoices.aspx" + vbCrLf & _
        " Kindly revert after approval. Thank you." + vbCrLf + "Regards."

    Dim To1, To2, To3 As String

    Dim mm As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    mm.From = New MailAddress("name@gmail.com")

    To1 = "usernameTo1@domain.com"
    To2 = "usernameTo2@domain.com"
    To3 = "usernameTo3@gmail.com"
    'To is a collection of MailAddress types
    mm.To.Add(To1)
    mm.To.Add(To2)
    mm.To.Add(To3)

    mm.Subject = subject
    mm.Body = body

    mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8
    'mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
    Try
        ss.Send(mm)
    Catch ex As SmtpException
        Me.lblerr.Text = "SMTP Err:" & ex.ToString
    End Try
```

So what could be making the mails not to reach their destination? I am not getting any error message at all. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For gmail, you need to set the port to 587.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myn@gmail.com ">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
          port="587" userName ="me@gmail.com" password="pass@123" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

Comment: Which he's done on the first line: `New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)` - the second parameter is the port number.

Comment: I tried running again and now I get an error: `The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'` After running a second time and turning my firewall off, I get another error: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.67.109:587`

Comment: Very generic error message. Could be a proxy issue, firewall issue, etc.

Comment: Comment out the last two port params; the 25 is what will be set the way you have it now.

Comment: @IrishChieftain i didn't edit the question, it's possible you didn't see it when you entered your answer. However, I have made a comment which i edited after first post. I hope it can give a clue as to what's causing this error. Thanks all